# SPI using pi4j on 4.4 Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, spi

With the recent exclusion of spi-bcm2708 from the 4.4 kernel, I'm left scratching my head as to whether or not pi4j's 1.1 release (or any other version) is capable of handling SPI.

Anybody else using this combination?

Comment: There wasn't such driver in the upstream.

Comment: You mean bcm2708? Yeah, it's deprecated on 4.4.

Comment: What's the name of the file? I can't find such in upstream.

Comment: Here is a reference to it; I just used it as an overlay when it was available: https://github.com/notro/spi-bcm2708/wiki

Comment: Have you read this wiki by yourself?! What is the first **Note:** there? Besides that I tried to make a hint you have to fix your question, i.e. two items are missed: kernel source and path to the module in question. Seems like you didn't do your homework.

Comment: Andy, I've read countless forums, documents, and have done hours & hours of testing to find out what's going on. I am not asking other people to do my work. Something has changed from kernel 4.1 to 4.4 that's breaking the system I've built over the past few years, and I need to get it fixed. I appreciate any help you can provide, but please don't lecture me on work ethic and stop with the quizzes.

Comment: Please, update a question. You have to put reference to a) Linux kernel sources you are using, b) path and file name of the module in question. I'm tired to repeat that there was **never** such file in upstream. And you already found the answer to your question, I doubt you got the text you referred to. If you are not going to do your homework (other people may tell you to read how to ask questions) no one believe me would like to help you. And now good news. It would be my last message in this thread until you start doing something.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you speak for yourself as opposed to everybody else. You keep asking a question that means absolutely nothing to me. Never such a file in upstream? What does that even mean? What file? What stream? I did a rpi-update on wheezy and bumped the kernel from 4.1 to 4.4, and that's where the problem started. 4.1 had spi-bcm2708 and was phased out in 4.4. The question is, what was in it that's now missing and is causing problems. I am not dodging your question. I don't understand it!